# Почему текстура перевёрнута?

Tags: unity3d, текстура

```
GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = Resources.Load("textures/1") as Texture;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может это объект, на который она наложена, перевернут,  а не текстура?

Comment: Это стандартное расположение объекта на осях

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучшим ли способом я делаю?

Поворачиваю внутри GameObject дочерний GameObject2 с повёрнутой координатой Rotation z 180

Взято отсюда http://www.gamedev.ru/code/forum/?id=163254

1. Самый простой. Создаем пустой GameObject, дочерним к нему делаем "снаряд" (Просто перетаскиваем "снаряд" на созданный пустой GameObject). Дальше поворачиваем дочерний "снаряд" так как необходимо.

Comment: Это ответ или продолжение вопроса?

Comment: Это неудачное решение.

Теперь не могу обратиться к вложенному объекту.

`GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture`

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html

Comment: Готово

`GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>().material.mainTexture`